# Demonstratives [Those, These] with Genitive

Tags: grammar

I wonder whether demonstrative pronouns can be appended Genitive 's. 
For instance;

> Those's cat is dead.

Is it those's cat? 
I know, I need to use "their cat" instead of it. 
So, have you ever heard about those's cat?

Comment: If you know it's "their cat", what makes you ask about "those's cat"?

Comment: I dont know, cruosity I think. So, can it be used?

Comment: Demonstratives are no longer inflected in English, so there's no genitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler Can we think of *any* determiner(ive) that takes a genitive? (assuming we aren't including pronouns). Can't right now, but don't have any kind of a list ...

Comment: _Whose_ is a genitive; whether it's a Determiner or a Pronoun within the meaning of the Act is a matter for someone else to judge.

Answer (score 2):

You can't say *those's cat*, even though you might be able to use *those's* for inanimate objects.

Although we use *those* as a pronominal adjective for people (i.e., *those women*), we don't use it as a pronoun for people; it's only used for inanimate objects and animals. Using *those* for people would either sound very insulting or very weird, depending on how you used it.

So you couldn't say

> *See those; their cat is dead,

either. You would have to say one of

> See those people; their cat is dead,
>   See them; their cat is dead.

And of course, *those people's cat* is perfectly grammatical, even though most of the time we use *their cat* instead.

For inanimate objects, you shouldn't use *those's* in formal English, but I don't think there's anything wrong with it for informal English. I can imagine somebody saying:

> These jar's lids fit, but those's don't.

One addendum: you can say

> I'll take care of these customers; you take care of those,

but that's because there's an implied "customers" after "those".

Comment: I think what you’re getting at is that, for people, *those* cannot be used with exophoric reference, only as a normal anaphor.